# Access files using server path not URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 questions.

1. I am currently running XAMP and I want to prohibit people from being able to open .xml files in /htdocs/db/resource/data. I believe this is a .htaccess solution.
2. I would also want to those .xml files from my PHP. Since I can't use URL file path, I tried just using 'resource/data/filename.xml' but it doesn't seem to work. I think I am missing something here.
3. Just to add if this factors in. I am using CI and it's installed in htdocs/db/ in my XAMPP. I can access the .xml via url but I would like to access it via file path in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, an Apache configuration will support this

   ```
   # /htdocs/db/resource/data/.htaccess

   <FilesMatch "\.xml$">
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
2. Should work, eg

   ```
   // /htdocs/db/some-file.php

   $xml = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ . '/resource/data/filename.xml');
   ```

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote. Care to comment, mystery downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

Define a constant for the root directory in the main file i.e. index.php

like this

```
if(!defined('SITEPATH')){
   define('SITEPATH',dirname(__FILE__).'/');
}
```

now you can go for any file as same as by using it like your r using the url.

enjoy

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
$xmls = array(
                'customxml_name1' => 'RelativePath1',
                'customxml_name2' => 'RelativePath2',
            );

if(isset($_GET['data'])&&!empty($_GET['data'])){
    echo file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$xmls[$_GET['data']]);
}
?>
```

Put this script in your root folder. add your paths to the xmls with their custom names then call the script url with the `get parameter` => `data` as the `customxml_name` of the xml.

Enjoy :)

Comment: I will be passing this on a javascript variable, which will expose my file path. Will that be ok?

Comment: lol, you should have specified javascript requirement in the question. NO this is only supported for the server side scripting. For JS only url method is available. Or you can use a script by url which calls your xml files as specified in the script

Comment: @mra : if you want to know how to implement that script feel free to comment

Comment: No this do not compromise the security.

Comment: @mra : Check my edit. **NOTE:** Paths must be relative to the script file.